# How to close a dialog box programmatically

Tags: javafx

please I need some assistance. I have this java fx project I am working on. The idea is to prevent the default windows close button behavior, and only close the dialog if login is successful.

Below is how I am able to set the dialog and prevent dialog closing.

```
public class MainController extends Application implements Initializable{

// Create a dialog
private Dialog<Pair<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();

/*Login resources*/
@FXML // fx:id="loginBtn"
private Button loginBtn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="usernameTxt"
private TextField usernameTxt; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="loginProgressIndicator"
private ProgressIndicator loginProgressIndicator; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="passwordTxt"
private PasswordField passwordTxt; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="statusLbl"
private Label statusLbl; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML
void login(ActionEvent event) {

    Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();

    stage.fireEvent(
            new WindowEvent(
                    stage,
                    WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST
            )
    );
}

/*Main Menu resources*/
@FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
private URL location;

@FXML // fx:id="visitBtn"
private Button visitBtn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="reportBtn"
private Button reportBtn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="setupBtn"
private Button setupBtn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML
void report(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void setup(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void visit(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Visit Button Pressed.");
}

/**
 * The main entry point for all JavaFX applications.
 * The start method is called after the init method has returned,
 * and after the system is ready for the application to begin running.
 * <p>
 * <p>
 * NOTE: This method is called on the JavaFX Application Thread.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param primaryStage the primary stage for this application, onto which
 *                     the application scene can be set. The primary stage will be embedded in
 *                     the browser if the application was launched as an applet.
 *                     Applications may create other stages, if needed, but they will not be
 *                     primary stages and will not be embedded in the browser.
 */
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Main Menu - PEHCS Point of Sale");

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show(); //This will display the main menu

    dialog.setTitle("Login - PEHCS Point of Sale");
    dialog.setHeaderText(null);


    // Get the Stage.
    Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    // Add a custom icon.
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("activa.jpg").toString()));


    /*This section prevents the dialog from closing when we press on the window X button*/
    Window window = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    window.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

        /**
         * Invoked when a specific event of the type for which this handler is
         * registered happens.
         *
         * @param event the event which occurred
         */
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            event.consume();
        }
    });


    /*Set th content of that dialog to be the login.fxml resource file*/
    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml")));


    Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();

    result.ifPresent(usernamePassword -> {
        System.out.println("Username=" + usernamePassword.getKey() + ", Password=" + usernamePassword.getValue());
    });

}

/**
 * Called to initialize a controller after its root element has been
 * completely processed.
 *
 * @param location  The location used to resolve relative paths for the root object, or
 *                  <tt>null</tt> if the location is not known.
 * @param resources The resources used to localize the root object, or <tt>null</tt> if
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    assert visitBtn != null : "fx:id=\"visitBtn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'main2.fxml'.";
    assert reportBtn != null : "fx:id=\"reportBtn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'main2.fxml'.";
    assert setupBtn != null : "fx:id=\"setupBtn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'main2.fxml'.";

    assert loginBtn != null : "fx:id=\"loginBtn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'login.fxml'.";
    assert usernameTxt != null : "fx:id=\"usernameTxt\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'login.fxml'.";
    assert loginProgressIndicator != null : "fx:id=\"loginProgressIndicator\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'login.fxml'.";
    assert passwordTxt != null : "fx:id=\"passwordTxt\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'login.fxml'.";
    assert statusLbl != null : "fx:id=\"statusLbl\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'login.fxml'.";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

The window close event is being consume in the on start method and it works. Now I want to close this dialog in th login methos. This is where I am stuck. Please I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Guys. I printed the address of the dialog variable in on start and in the login function and there ae different. So this means that the variable use to set is not the sam use to close, hence it won't close. Can someone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

To close the window programmatically, all you need is

```
@FXML
void login(ActionEvent event) {

    dialog.close();

}
```

Note that this will not trigger an `onCloseRequest` handler, which is only invoked for an *external* request to close the window (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty)).